# How to install new packages into non-root Docker Container?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to extend a docker container for SOLR. I just want to install `vim` into it. But when I run the docker build it complains that I'm not root.

This is the DockerFile that I'm extending:
https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr/blob/master/5.3/Dockerfile

And my build file is this:

```
FROM makuk66/docker-solr
MAINTAINER OCSCommerce Team <support@ocscommerce.com>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install vim
COPY home/ocscommerce /etc/solr/home
```

Then it outputs this:

```
192.168.99.100
localhost:solr$ docker build -t ocscommerce/solr .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 39.66 MB
Step 0 : FROM makuk66/docker-solr
 ---> 92be2fe79f15
Step 1 : MAINTAINER OCSCommerce Team <support@ocscommerce.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a3ac70e40324
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in c865716a2694
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Is there any way to install a package into this container? Or would I need to copy the original build file from makuk66?

Comment: So, tell me the purpose that you need install vim in container? normally it is not required.

Comment: well I often log on to the terminal and need to look at files if I'm investigating some problem.

Comment: You need vim to look at log files? Then you should map an external volume to `/var/log/solr` or wherever they are stored. Plus, that allows persistent log files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [Dockerfile#L24](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr/blob/master/5.3/Dockerfile#L24), the user has been switched to `solr`. So if you use the image as base image with `FROM`, all commands in your own `Dockerfile` are running by the user `solr`

You can fix it by building the Dockerfile from beginning.

```
FROM    java:openjdk-8-jre
MAINTAINER  Martijn Koster "mak-docker@greenhills.co.uk"

ENV SOLR_VERSION 5.3.0
ENV SOLR solr-$SOLR_VERSION
ENV SOLR_USER solr

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install lsof && \
  groupadd -r $SOLR_USER && \
  useradd -r -g $SOLR_USER $SOLR_USER && \
  mkdir -p /opt && \
  wget -nv --output-document=/opt/$SOLR.tgz http://www.us.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/$SOLR_VERSION/$SOLR.tgz && \
  tar -C /opt --extract --file /opt/$SOLR.tgz && \
  rm /opt/$SOLR.tgz && \
  ln -s /opt/$SOLR /opt/solr && \
  mkdir -p /opt/solr/server/solr/lib && \
  chown -R $SOLR_USER:$SOLR_USER /opt/solr /opt/$SOLR

RUN apt-get --assume-yes install vim

EXPOSE 8983
WORKDIR /opt/solr
USER $SOLR_USER
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/solr/bin/solr -f"]
```

Second, don't copy the codes to container when building, use `-v` option will be more flexible.

```
COPY home/ocscommerce /etc/solr/home
```

Replace with `docker run` command `-v home/ocscommerce:/etc/solr/home`

Comment: ok, I suspected I might have to copy the image file. No worries thank for the tips.

Answer (score 141):

Switch to the `root` user, then switch back to the original `solr` user:

```
USER root

install/updates

USER solr
```

Comment: Would you mind explaing what is this supposed to do?

Comment: For me just enter this line in my Dockerfile which extends other and I solve problem right on installation package : 'USER root'. Just that !

Comment: It changes the user to root so that you can run privileged commands like `apt-get install`. After this is done, it switches back to the user called `solr` which seems created from the original image, so that the application inside the container doesn't have to run with root privileges (which is a good practice in general). You only need this when the base image creator care about security. Cause when he don't, everything runs with full root privileges inside the container, which is the default behavior of docker.

Comment: is this actually safe?

Answer (score 90):

Similar suggestion to the previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37615312/2200690, open an interactive shell as the root user and then install your packages using apt-get.

```
docker exec --user="root" -it <container_name> /bin/bash
```

install the package

```
apt-get install package
```

Comment: This one works for me

Comment: is this actually safe?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error when using bitnami spark image and docker exec command with arguments -u didn't work for me. I found my answer in the image documentation [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/work-with-non-root-containers/).

I believe you are using a non root container image. Read the documents of the docker image provider to find the solution to see how you can use the image as a root container image.