# Running pipelines with an android build environment image and ruby

Tags: android, ruby, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using the following yml file

```
image: uber/android-build-environment:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - bundler
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y awscli
          - apt-get install rubygems
          - gem install bundler
          - bundle install
          - bundle exec fastlane test
          - bundle exec fastlane build
definitions:
  caches:
    bundler: ./vendor
```

Please notice that I'm using an Android build environment image.

The build fails on

apt-get install rubygems
with the error:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission
>   denied)E: Unable to lock the administration directory
>   (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

so it looks like the build script does not run as root.

If I try to use `sudo`, it fails with the error

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

What should I do to be able to run ruby gems with an Android build environment image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uber/android-build-environment:latest` uses a non-root user, which doesn't have permissions to run some commands, for example `apt-get`. You should rebuild an image with root user or temporary change the user to root. In your `Dockerfile` add:

```
USER root

install/updates

USER solr
```

See more details about the issue here [How to install new packages into non-root Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576928/how-to-install-new-packages-into-non-root-docker-container)

P.S. You don't need to run pipeline as root. If you run under the root inside the docker container, you will be able to install your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using a different android build env image:

```
image: mingc/android-build-box:v1.2.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
          - gradlewrapper
          - androidavd
          - bundler
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y awscli
          - gem update --system
          - gem install bundler
          - gem install danger
          - bundle install
          - bundle exec fastlane test
          - bundle exec fastlane build
definitions:
  caches:
    gradlewrapper: ~/.gradle/wrapper
    androidavd: $ANDROID_HOME/.android/avd
    bundler: ./vendor
```